# Opencms 15.0 - detail page show 404

Tags: opencms

I have opencms 15.0
I followed the documentation to create a list view and e detail page:
https://documentation.opencms.org/opencms-documentation/template-development/detail-pages/index.html

I configured the detail page correctly but opencms gives me 404.
My detail page is /articles/detail.html

If in the map configuration instead of using the following path **/articles/detail.html** I use the path **/articles** it works and I see the detail page.

What am I doing wrong?